# conditional distribution question

Tags: probability, distributions, conditional-probability

I have a joint distribution which factorizes as follows:

$$
P(y, w, \beta) = P(y|\beta, w) P(w) P(\beta)
$$

Now, I want to write the conditional distribution for $P(w|y, \beta)$, so this should be written as:

$$
P(w|y, \beta) = \frac{P(y, w, \beta)}{P(y, \beta)}
= \frac{P(y|\beta, w) P(w) P(\beta)}{P(y|\beta) P(\beta)}
\propto P(y|\beta, w) P(w) 
$$

I am not sure of the last step but I am guessing the denominator does not depend on $w$, we can treat it like a constant. My question is whether I can find the maxima for $P(w|y, \beta)$ by finding the maxima of $P(y|\beta, w) P(w)$ i.e. treat the $P(y|\beta)$ denominator as a constant. I am trying to do this in the context of figuring out some variational bayes updates where I need to compute some expectations and need the conditional distributions to do that.

Comment: Correct: $p(w\mid y,\beta)\propto p(w,y,\beta)\propto p(y\mid\beta,w)p(w)$, which is a mnemonic for "discard" things that do not depend on $w$. Normalize at the end, if necessary.

Comment: Luca you don't seem to actually ask question here, just make statements. What exactly do you need?

Comment: I was wondering if I could find the maxima of $P(w|y, \beta)$ by optimising just $P(y|\beta, w)P(w)$. Sorry I was not clear with that.

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering if I could find the maxima of $P(w|y, \beta)$ by optimizing just    $P(y|\beta, w) P(w)$.

You can because you are doing a discriminate task and you don't need to care about the denominator which is a constant for every element you are going to compare. If you are doing a generative task you need to calculate the exact result of the $P(w|y, \beta)$ and hence to work out the $p(y, \beta)$.

So in your case $$
P(w|y, \beta) = \frac{P(y, w, \beta)}{P(y, \beta)}
= P(y|\beta, w) P(w) * \frac{P(\beta)}{P(y, \beta)}
\propto P(y|\beta, w) P(w) 
$$